# How to include additional properties when using structured logging with NLog?

Tags: vb.net, nlog

I know you can do this:

```
_Logger.Info("This is my message: {MessageId}.  And here's an explanation: {expl}", messageId, expl)
```

which will insert the value of messageId and expl into the message like String.Format, based on their order in the string.

Unfortunately, I want to add extra properties beyond those from the structured message logging, so I'm using LogEventInfo:

```
Dim ev as New LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Info, "", "This is my message: {MessageId}")
ev.Properties{"EventId"}=eventId
_Logger.Log(ev)
```

Are there other ways for adding additional properties in an elegant way?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you interested in building a complex message-template that the LogEvent can use for formatting the output-message? Or are you interested in adding many properties to the LogEvent? Maybe read https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging

Comment: Julian, sorry I didn't notice this comment when it came in.  My issue is combining the need to add several properties with a structured logging message concisely.  I figured it out on my own doing something slightly different than your answer below, but I'll respond there.

Comment: Have now updated your question to match the answer that was accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `WithProperty` to add properties which aren't in the message.

Example:

```
_Logger.WithProperty("EventId", eventId)
       .Info("This is my message: {MessageId}.  And here's an explanation: {expl}", messageId, expl)
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Context#logevent-properties

Comment: This looks exactly like what I needed.  To anyone else coming across this answer, you can chain WithProperty to add additional properties: 
`_Logger.WithProperty("EventId", eventId).WithProperty("AddtlInfo", moreInfo).Info("This is my message: {MessageId}.  And here's an explanation: {expl}", messageId, expl)`

I actually solved this a little differently using fluent: 
`_Logger.Info().Message("This is my message: {MessageId}.  And here's an explanation: {expl}", messageId, expl).Property("EventId", eventId).Property("AddtlInfo", moreInfo).Write()`

I like your approach better, though.